# what does the v5.0 in the name of an e-book file stand for?

Tags: epub, html, ocr

I have seen various e-books on the Internet that have a `(v5.0)` in the name e.g.

```
Charles Darwin - On the Origin of Species (v5.0).epub
```

Initially I thought this had to with the version 5 of the DocBook, but I have seen other versions (v3.4) that do not have a corresponding DocBook version.
I have also seen this for e-books in `.html` and `.txt` files. Nothing in the those or the `.epub` file points at DocBook in any way.

What does this `(v5.0)` stand for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an indication of the **quality** of the ebook. `(v5.0)`  should be
close to retail quality:

```
v1.x: publication has been scanned and OCR-ed, but not spell checked.
v2.x: publication has been scanned, OCR-ed, and spell checked but not proofread.
v3.x: publication has been scanned, OCR-ed, spell checked, and proofread.
V4.x: publication has been proofread by multiple persons and is near retail quality.
v5.x: publication is of retail quality.
```

Minor version numbers are normally used for committed/uploaded changes.

I have not come across any (semi-)official website for these indications. I pulled these from my notes that I made while doing book scans myself. I think they came from some Usenet post.

Some v5 material still has a lot of errors (especially older publications where the fonts are not easily recognised by the OCR).

Comment: surely just means it is the 5th release

Comment: @Mark Not for the Major number. For the minor version number, you could see that as a release. It seems to be mostly used when multiple people make cooperative reviews